# Error on using org-babel-load-file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel

I am trying to write  emacs init using Org-mode By using **org-babel-load-file** function in **init.el**. My init.el file is

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives    
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
         '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
         )
(package-initialize)
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'use-package))
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "settings.org"
                   user-emacs-directory))
```

But on using so I am getting the following error message

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  expand-file-name(nil)
  load-file(nil)
  org-babel-load-file("/home/nithin/.emacs.d/settings.org")
  eval((org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "settings.org" user-emacs-directory)) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

I would appreciate any input on the subject.

Comment: Do you include the elisp code in src blocks with the `:tangle yes`  header argument?

Comment: I'm really new to Emacs. I think I haven't included that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by `org-babel-load-file` docstring (`C-h f`):

> Load Emacs Lisp source code blocks in the Org-mode FILE.
>   This function exports the source code using `org-babel-tangle`
>   and then loads the resulting file using `load-file`.

Your stack trace suggests there's a problem with the tangling (`load-file` is provided a `nil` arg as the file name).

Src blocks are [tangled according to their header argument](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html#Extracting-source-code):

> Header arguments
>
> **:tangle no**
>       The default. The code block is not included in the tangled output.
>
> **:tangle yes**
>       Include the code block in the tangled output. The output file name is the name of the org file with the extension ‘.org’ replaced by the extension for the block language.
>
> **:tangle filename**
>       Include the code block in the tangled output to file ‘filename’.

So you could add a `:tangle yes` header arg to the source blocks in file `settings.org`.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue with my `org` settings file. The reason behind was that I used `#+BEGIN_SRC elisp` instead of `#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp`. Therefore, the function `org-babel-load-file` considered that there was no elisp code to execute and return `nil`.

I wasn't aware of that solution early because the code highlight was activated. According to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34475/23697), `elisp` is an alias of `emacs-lisp`. You can check if you have the function `org-babel-execute:elisp` defined. In my case, I had only `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp`, that's why it didn't work.