# orgmode - babel language elisp vs. emacs-lisp

Tags: org-mode

I am not sure what's the difference between elisp and emacs-lisp.
In my environment, both work for elisp code but I did not found elisp from the load language list:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(print org-babel-load-languages)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: ((emacs-lisp . t) (python . t) (ipython . t) (plantuml . t) (dot . t) (calc . t) (C . t) (latex . t) (sqlite . t) (java . t) (shell . t))
```

Comment: Elisp is Emacs Lisp. The preferred name is apparently Emacs Lisp, but the menu item in Info for the manual is named `Elisp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works because the function `org-babel-execute:elisp` exists.  Looking at the help for that function shows

> org-babel-execute:elisp is an alias for ‘org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp’
>   in ‘ob-emacs-lisp.el’.
>
> (org-babel-execute:elisp BODY PARAMS)
>
> Execute a block of emacs-lisp code with Babel.

So `emacs-lisp` is the "real" name and `elisp` is  just a convenient shorthand.  You could make more such shortcuts using `defalias`.  For example to have "py" source blocks instead of "python" use

```
(defalias 'org-babel-execute:py 'org-babel-execute:python)
```